# C: brightyellow and brightgreen colors (ncurses)?

Tags: c, ncurses

I have been looking for nice colors such as mc has for yellow and green.

In ncurses, you can specify those RGB:

> 10.2. Changing Color Definitions
>
> The function init_color()can be used to change the rgb values for the
>   colors defined by curses initially. Say you wanted to lighten the
>   intensity of red color by a minuscule. Then you can use this function
>   as
>
> ```
> init_color(COLOR_RED, 700, 0, 0);
> /* param 1     : color name
>  * param 2, 3, 4 : rgb content min = 0, max = 1000 */
> ```

I couldnt find bright yellow or bright green colors. Aren't they included by default in ncurses?

Regards,
Ulrich

Comment: Usually the bright colors are the bolded ones. Bold your text.

Comment: I haven't used ncurses for a while now but as I remember there are only 8 colours by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can have "full" color but you need to recompile your ncurses to support it (and have something that can show it)

> "To compile NCurses with 256 color support, use this option:"

```
--enable-ext-colors
```

ref: http://www.c-for-dummies.com/ncurses/256color.php according to Thomas Dickey, NCurses' maintainer and Dan Gookin

```
Color   Function                        Constant Name
0       init_color(0,0,0,0);            COLOR_BLACK
1       init_color(0,1000,0,0);         COLOR_RED
2       init_color(0,0,1000,0);         COLOR_GREEN
3       init_color(0,1000,1000,0);      COLOR_YELLOW
4       init_color(0,0,0,1000);         COLOR_BLUE
5       init_color(0,1000,0,1000);      COLOR_MAGENTA
6       init_color(0,0,1000,1000);      COLOR_CYAN
7       init_color(0,1000,1000,1000);   COLOR_WHITE
```

- It is possible to get more than the standard 8 (or 16) colors out of NCurses...

Your TERM environment variable may also be `xterm` try changing that to `xterm-256color`

Answer (score 0):

The number of colors and color pairs (bg + fg) supported by the terminal is returned by functions:

```
COLOR()
COLOR_PAIRS()
```

As [solusipse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2031025/solusipse) correctly points out, there should be 8 colors by default (there are only 8 defined in `curses.h`).

The `init_color()` call might be supported by the terminal, but most probably it won't. You can check it issuing a call to:

```
can_change_color().
```

[Pubby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/964135/pubby) correctly pointed out, that bolding (with `A_BOLD`) can brighter the text, allowing you for a total of 16 colors, though only for the foreground color.

On my system, `xterm`, `gnome-terminal` and `konsole` behave exactly the same; they report 8 colors, 64 color pairs, `can_change_color()` is false and the `A_BOLD` attribute indeed lightens the fg color.

Answer (score 0):

```
   main()
   {
    initscr();
    if (start_color() == OK)
    {
        init_pair (1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_GREEN);
        attron (COLOR_PAIR (1));
        if (init_color (COLOR_RED, 0, 0, 1000) == OK)
            addstr ("BLUE ON GREEN");
        else
            addstr ("RED ON GREEN");
        getch ();
    }
    endwin();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you could do is to create a new color which would have teh name

COLOR_BRIGHT_YELLOW  to the color number 8

COLOR_BRIGHT_GREEN to the color number 9

but I have never made it and it is not so much documented.

Answer (score 0):

If you want bright colors, then you must use:

```
attrxxx(COLOR_PAIR(COLOR_xxxxx) | A_BOLD)
```

So to get bright yellow, one would use:

```
attr_t color_bright_yellow = COLOR_PAIR(COLOR_YELLOW) | A_BOLD;
```

etc.
(Note if you want more colors, compile [to be more specific, `./configure`] ncurses with `--with-ext-colors` enabled.)